# Can I tell when a query is running in SSMS vs elsewhere?

Tags: ssms, pragma

Is there any kind of environment variable (or something) that will tell me if a script is running inside SSMS? For example at the top of my query in SSMS I have this:

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @ThisYear datetime, @IncludeZeroBalance int;
set @StartDate = '20080101';
set @EndDate = '20170201';
set @ThisYear = year(GetDate());
set @IncludeZeroBalance = 0;
```

I'd like to be able to leave that in the query but "wrap" it with something so it's only seen/run when in SSMS. Some kind of pragma like **#IF SSMS** or similar.

I'm thinking there's not something like this (searching has proven fruitless) but am hoping someone knows a trick to do that kind of thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `APP_NAME()` function to get the name of the application that the calling application specified in its `connectionstring`. Example:

```
declare @MyAppname nvarchar(50);
select @MyAppname = app_name();
if (@MyAppname = 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query')
    begin
        print 'Do SSMS stuff here'
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'Do non-SSMS stuff here'
    end;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I was looking for!